# Which Linux commands are available after WSL activation, but without to install Linux?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After activation of Linux subsystem on Windows 10 I realized that there are some Linux commands, which are available without of Linux installation. I.e. `curl` works.

As a newbie I thought firstly, `curl` would be not a Linux, but a Msdos command - but in the list of all `CMD` commands for Windows10, [i.e. here](https://www.lifewire.com/list-of-command-prompt-commands-4092302), it isn't.

So my question is: what Linux commands are available on Windows 10 after Linux subsystem activation, but without to install Linux?

Comment: "So my question is: what Linux commands are available on Windows 10 after Linux subsystem activation, but without installing Linux?" - WSL2 runs a literal Linux kernel.  Any command you can run on a stand-alone Linux machine you should be able to run within WSL2. Asking for a literal list of commands is way to broad of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curl` isn't a shell command, it's a command line utility program.  It can be downloaded and run in any Windows shell (CMD, Powershell...).  The same as Linux, except it is included out of the box with several distributions.  No commands get added to Windows by enabling WSL.  WSL runs native Linux binaries so there is no possibility for cross-over between the Linux distribution(s) within WSL and Windows with regards to the binary executables.